# How to make eval() use passed "locals"?

Tags: python, eval, python-3.7, lazy-evaluation

In order to do lazy evaluation of an expression, I am using Python 3.7's [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to produce a `function`.

I am successfully passing data via `eval`'s `globals`, but `locals` seem totally ignored.

Simple example:

```
my_globals = dict(a='from globals')
my_locals = dict(a='from locals', b='ok')
lazy = eval("lambda: f'{a}'", my_globals, my_locals)
print(lazy())
>>> from globals
```

So `globals` seems to override `locals`. And it works fine for my intended use:

```
my_globals['a'] = "on a different context..."
print(lazy())
>>> on a different context...
```

But if I try to access `b` in `my_locals`:

```
lazy_b = eval("lambda: f'{b}'", my_globals, my_locals)
print(lazy_b())

>>> NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

And the same if I try creating the context before or after the call:

```
lazy_b = eval("lambda: f'{b}'", my_globals, my_locals)
def local_context(b):
    print(lazy_b())
local_context('Not even this one')

>>> NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

I could live with just `my_globals` on my specific use case, but this seems a mystery worth unveiling...

What is `eval()` (not) doing with `my_locals`?

Comment: Why do you need to use `eval()` to do lazy evaluation? I don't follow your logic

Comment: why exactly are you doing this, this sounds like a nightmare waiting to happen

Comment: In any case, it doesn't seem like you need `eval` at all. Just don't use it?

Comment: `"(lambda a: lambda: f'{a}')(a)"` will work, not that it ever really makes sense. So the duplicate answers your question *about* `eval`, but to echo what’s been said, `eval` is probably not the correct solution for you anyway.

Comment: Thanks, @Ry. I realize that lambda does not inherit locals.

Comment: For those rabious about me trying to use eval safely to build a function from an (user provided) f-string, that was just not the point here.

Comment: “from an (user provided) f-string” sounds even less safe and less necessary, since `str.format` exists…

Comment: `str.format` cannot parse expressions. I thought that was obvious. I don't get why people insist so much on something off-topic!